# Save the contents of a ServletContext attribute in an int variable

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, int

In the first JSP I create a servletcontext in which I put a Count attribute with num value, in the second JSP simple I get the Count value from that context, but it gives me error. How can I save an object of type servletcontext in an array ??

```
jsp1:
<%!int num=0;%>
<%ServletContext cont = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
  num++;
  cont.setAttribute("Conta",num);
%>

jsp2:
<% ServletContext cont = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
   int contator=Integer.parseInt(cont.getAttribute("Conta"));
%>
```

Comment: What error does it give?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without the error, but I think I may have found it.

You are hitting an error when Integer.parseInt(String) receives an int/Integer, which is throwing most likely a method not found error. In this case [void setAttribute(String, Object)] will take the integer you are passing it and [Object getAttribute(String)] will return the integer. Integer.parseInt(String) will then fail.

If you refactor to not do the Integer.parseInt() and just cast the result to the int, you should be OK.